# Converting specific sheet and column from text to number

Tags: excel, vba

I am using a code I found in another thread to convert a column from text to number:

```
[E:E].Select
With Selection
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

This runs in the current tab/sheet I am currently in but my workbook has several tabs and I only want it to run in one sheet. What would I need to add to the code to only run in one specified sheet?

Comment: Remove `[E:E].Select`, then change `With Selection` to `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Yoursheetname").Range("E:E")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```vb
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("XXXX")    '--> insert your sheets name

Dim rg As Range
Set rg = ws.Range("E:E")

With rg
    .NumberFormat = "General"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```

Select is not needed - maybe this is interesting for you [How to avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/16578424)